# Braintree Exception ServerError

Tags: braintree

I am using `Braintree` payment method since last 2 year. Its was working perfectly, but now there some issue with sandbox environment. it's throw an error `"Braintree_Exception_SSLCertificate"` Although same source code working perfectly on production.
Please suggestion me the cause of this error and how I can fix it.

Comment: this will work well with SSL, did you manage to work it with your localmachine.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).

The Sandbox environment was updated on 13th December and TLS 1.2 is the only supported protocol now (This was announced in our TLS 1.2 update page [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/updating-your-production-environment-to-support-tlsv1-2/)). Therefore, you'll need to check your server configuration and make sure that it can support connections over TLS 1.2 protocol. You can find more details about TLS 1.2 requirements by clicking [here](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update). Production environment will be updated on January 31st of this month.

Comment: what do i have to do to make sandbox work on my local machine ? i use MAMP.